# Any productivity tip for using OS X with only one arm, like Windows its sticky key?

Tags: macos, keyboard, accessibility

Google mostly returns Apple's accessibility API and other programming resources.

But I'd want to know, for example, what is Mac OS X version 10.7.4 equivalent of 'sticky key' in Windows.

Any other productivity tip for using OS X with only one arm?

Comment: May I also suggest http://www.matias.ca/halfkeyboard/index.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In **System Preferences**, click **Universal Access** then **Keyboard**:[image]

You'll find the options for sticky keys in there.

Answer (score 0):

Something I find very useful when on one arm (and when on two) is these:

- ctrl-a/e = jump to start/end of line
- ctrl-j/d = one line up/down
- ctrl-k = kill line from pointer to end of line
- ctrl-d = delete

They're maybe more useful if you're using you left arm, since you can then do most of them with your left pinky on ctrl.

For adding custom commands I recommend BetterTouchTool.