# Disable sticky keys only while certain applications have focus?

Tags: accessibility

Is there any way to enable sticky keys in OS X but automatically disable them while in certain applications?

Modifying system files and heavy terminal use is ok.

Here's a [screenshot of the preference pane containing Sticky keys](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55772/any-productivity-tip-for-using-os-x-with-only-one-arm-like-windows-its-sticky-k) for reference.

My specific case is virtualisation of Win 7 in Virtual Box on OSX 10.7.5

Comment: You mean the press and hold to get the special chars? What version of OSX are we talking about?

Comment: Yes! Clarified in my question, its OSX 10.7.5

Comment: If you always quit the application in question after using it, then I can imagine a possible solution. Otherwise I'm not sure. Assuming you do quit the app after using it, you could set a script up to watch which apps were open, then edit the preference file when it detected the app opening or closing. (I'm not skilled enough to write the script unfortunately.)

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like it to toggle on and off as I switch between virtualbox and other OSX applications.

Comment: I don't think you can do that without attempting some sort of Applescript that disables it when VirtualBox is in the front… but It's certainly nothing "native".