# How do I enable/disable sticky keys programmatically?

Tags: keyboard, applescript, accessibility, macos

I want to disable sticky keys on certain apps. To do so, I need a way to programmatically toggle the sticky keys settings. Is there a way to do this? I am okay with compiling a binary/Applescript/etc..

Here is the setting in the macOS GUI, for reference:
[image]

I have tried the following:

```
defaults read com.apple.universalaccess stickyKey
```

I can also write it but it does not take effect:

```
defaults write com.apple.universalaccess stickyKey 0
```

I tried killing these, which didn't quite work either.

```
killall cfprefsd

# I have also killed these two manually:
# /System/Library/CoreServices/UniversalControl.app/Contents/MacOS/UniversalControl
# /usr/sbin/universalaccessd launchd -s
```

Comment: I closed https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81523/disable-sticky-keys-only-while-certain-applications-have-focus as a duplicate to this one here. Neither has answers so far, so let's keep the more current one active.